# "Ignore built-in trackpad when mouse is present" not working

Tags: macos, mouse, trackpad

The built-in trackpad of my Mid-2012 13" MacBook Pro (running macOS Catalina 10.15.6) started to malfunction and I have tried everything from an SMC reset to an NVRAM reset but to no avail could I get it working.

I then purchased a Logitech M590 mouse as a replacement for my trackpad. When I go to *System Preferences → Accessibility → Pointer Control*  and check the *Ignore built-in trackpad when mouse or wireless trackpad is present* the laptop still accepts inputs from the mouse. However,  when I use another wireless mouse or use the Unifying receiver that comes with the Logitech mouse the computer no longer accepts inputs from the built-in trackpad.

Is there any way I can fix my built-in trackpad or use the Logitech mouse without its receiver. I feel like the problem lies in the way macOS interacts with the Logitech mouse.

Comment: I'm really not certain what you are asking for here. One mouse allows the trackpad to still work [which it shouldn't], another correctly disables it. What does that have to do with using the Logitech without the Unifying dongle? The way to 'fix' the trackpad is probably to replace a swollen battery.

Comment: When using the Logitech mouse with the dongle the "ignore built-in trackpad ...." works correctly, ie rejecting any input from the trackpad. but when I connect the mouse by Bluetooth without using the dongle the trackpad registers inputs from both the mouse and the trackpad. The problem still persists when I have physically taken the battery out of the laptop and run it when its connected to the power adaptor.

Comment: Then use the dongle.

Comment: You never said if you paired the M90 via Bluetooth or not.  It's not going to work until you do that and I'm assuming that since your trackpad isn't working, you need the mouse to navigate - you need to use the dongle until it's properly paired.  Either way - get the trackpad repaired.